# Dynamic label of a popup action in eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse-plugin, popupmenu

I want to create a simple eclipse plugin, which does: When you right click a java project, it will show a popup menu which has a item has label "N java files found in this project", where "N" is the file count.

I have an idea that I can update the label in "selectionChanged":

```
public class CountAction implements IObjectActionDelegate {
    public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {
        action.setText(countJavaFiles());
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work if I don't click that menu item, since the `CountAction` has not been loaded, that `selectionChanged` won't be invoked when you right-click on the project.

I have spent a lot of time on this, but not solved. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found a very easy way to implement this:

I don't need to change my code(the sample code in question), but I need to add a small `startup` class:

```
import org.eclipse.ui.IStartup;

public class MyStartUp implements IStartup {

    @Override
    public void earlyStartup() {
        // Initial the action
        new CountAction();
    }
}
```

And add following to `plugin.xml`:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.startup">
  <startup
        class="myplugin.MyStartUp">
  </startup>
```

This `MyStartUp` will load an instance of that action at startup, then `selectionChanged` will be invoked each time when I right-click the projects or files.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the article suggested by @kett_chup, is to use `IElementUpdater`. Simply

- your `handler` must implement `IElementUpdater`
- the `handler.updateElement((UIElement element, Map parameters)` must set the wanted text using `element.setText("new text")` - this new text will show up in menus and toolbars
- whenever you need/want to update the command text use `ICommandService.refreshElements(String commandId, Map filter)` with your particular command ID - the global command service usually is just fine

The `IElementUpdater` interface can also be used to change the checked state - for commands with `style=toggle` - as well as the icons and the tool tip.

Comment: I followed @kett_chup's answer, and it works. I'm very interested in your answer, but I don't understand how to implement it. For example, is the `handler` here is the `MyHandler` there? Are the other things still needed(CompoundContributionItem, command)?